# 2-column layout with fixed content width, unlimited background width

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to implement a layout for a website. Actually it is a simple 2-column layout where each column has its own background color. The content, however has a fixed width and it should be centered. The breaking point is the background, which should not be limited by the content width.

To illustrate the situation I have also made a picture:

[image]

I already had the idea to use a centered background image that I could tile vertically, but this solution would make the website's maximum width dependent on the width of the image.

What do you think, is there a better solution?

Thanks in advance
David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use an image as you bg, then the image should span a minimum of 960px, the first 640px being one colour and the right 320px should be the other colour.

If you want the bg to span the entire site, then you have to create a background large enough to span the first 1024px with the above column dimensions I mentioned. Add this to your CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    background:url("my image here") 0 0 repeat-y;
}
```

If you want to use colours only, just set the following attributes for each `col` class in the CSS:

```
col1 { background-color:#fff; }
col2 { background-color:#ccc; }
```

Assuming the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="col1">
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try the following CSS:

```
// This will create a wrapper across the entire page.
.wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
}

// This is your centered column
.content {
    float:left;
    width:960px;
}

// This is your first column
.col1 {
    background: **your background goes here
    float:left;
    width:640px;
}

// This is your second column
.col2 {
    background: **your background goes here
    float:left;
    width:320px;
}
```

If you want the bg to span the entire site, then you have to create a background large enough to span the first 1024px with the above column dimensions I mentioned.

Comment: Okay, this creates a fixed width 2-column layout. But how can I set the backgrounds as illustrated in my image.

Comment: @davidknezic, see the edits at the bottom of my answer. If you are using a plain colour, don't bother with an image, just assign the bg colour in each col class. col1 { background-color:#fff; } and col2 { background-color:#ccc; } That would solve it. If you want to use an image, see my edits at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Yes, I want the bg to span the entire website (100% of the width). On the left of the first column the bg should be white, on the right of the second column it should be gray. So you think I should make a large enough bg image, containing the two colors, that I can set as the centered background of .wrapper?

Comment: @davidknezic, yes! There is another way to do it, but that will require some messy HTML and CSS. So I would create a large bg. I would make the height 1px and repeat-x. This was the image will still be small, but it will give you two colours.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, this solution would make the website's maximum width dependent on the width of the image. But it is probably the cleanest way to solve this.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @davidknezic, unfortunately, you have little choice here. It's either that, or create a really messy CSS HTML combo where you create massive margins or padding, and/or empty layers as "holders". It would be highly unorthodox and unsymantic. This is the cleanest way. I would not recommend any other way.

Comment: Okay, but shouldn't it be repeat-y instead of repeat-x?

Comment: @davidknezic, yes, sorry, I confused myself.

Comment: No problem, just to avoid any unnecessary confusion :). I'll accept your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @davidknezic, --never mind, ignore this comment. I figured it out-- I'm just curious as to why you need the image in such a way. Why not use a colour (or a tiny image) for the main background, then use another color or bg image for each column... ?

Comment: The columns are just one part of the whole website. If I change their appearance they would not fit in the overall picture. But I will see if it is worth the effort when I finish it.

Answer (score 0):

YUI offers very good solution for the grid layout please check it, see if it helps.
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/

Comment: Wow, this is nice to create grid layouts quickly. But I am not sure if it can solve my problem.